# How to navigate from a component class in React Native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I want to simply navigate from Home Screen to Creator Screen. I can easily navigate between them if i place the link directly in my Home Class, but I have created a Cards component class for all my creators, now I can't navigate from my Cards Class. Any idea how? The code in below is not working. I got error said that **Can't find variable: navigation.**

[my Home scree screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rlk1q.png)

Any one would help? Big thanks.

I tired to make my Cards Class like this, but then my `imageUri` became a new problem. So i removed it, the current Cards Class is in below.

```
    const Cards = ({navigation}) => (
      <View style={{padding: 30, flexDirection: 'row', borderBottomColor: '#6a6a6a', borderBottomWidth: 0.4}}>
        <View>
           <Image source={this.props.imageUri} style={styles.profileIcon} />
           <Image source={images.broShakeLogo} style={styles.broShakeLogo} />
        </View>
        <View style={{paddingLeft: 40, flexDirection: 'column'}}>
             .....
              <TouchableOpacity
              onPress={() => navigation.navigate('creator')} >
           .....
    );
```

Here's my stack navigator

```
    const HomeStack = createStackNavigator ({
      home: {
        screen: HomeScreen,
      },
      creator: {
        screen: CreatorScreen
      },
    },
    {
      headerMode: 'none'
    });
```

And here's my Home Class

```
    class Home extends Component {
        return (
          <View style={styles.container}>
            <ScrollView>
              <View style={styles.welcomContainer}>
              {/* so this one in here actually works fine but i want them wrap inside my Cards Class */}
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('creator')}>
                  <CT.ReadmoreText/>
                </TouchableOpacity>
              </View>
              <Cards imageUri={require('../assets/images/cprofile_2.jpg')} distance="30" navigation={this.props.navigation}/>
              <Cards imageUri={require('../assets/images/cprofile_1.jpg')} distance="34" />
              <Cards imageUri={require('../assets/images/cprofile_1.jpg')} distance="20" />
              <Cards imageUri={require('../assets/images/cprofile_3.jpg')} distance="10" />
            </ScrollView>
          </View>
        );
      }
    }
    export default Home;
```

Here's my Cards class

```
    class Cards extends Component {
       render() {
         <View style={styles.container}>
           <View style={{padding: 30, flexDirection: 'row', borderBottomColor: '#6a6a6a', borderBottomWidth: 0.4}}>
             <View>
               <Image source={this.props.imageUri} style={styles.profileIcon} />
               <Image source={images.broShakeLogo} style={styles.broShakeLogo} />
             </View>
             <View style={{paddingLeft: 40, flexDirection: 'column'}}>
               <Icon name="location-arrow" type="FontAwesome" 
              style={{ color: "#00d278" ,fontSize: 18 }} >
                 <Text style={styles.distanceText}> {this.props.distance} m</Text>
               </Icon>
               <Text style={styles.locationText}>Atomica</Text>
               <Text style={styles.cityText}>MELBOURNE</Text>
               <View style={{paddingTop: 18}}>
                 <TouchableOpacity
              onPress={() => navigation.navigate('creator')}
              >
                   <CT.ReadmoreText/>
                 </TouchableOpacity>
               </View>
             </View>
           </View>
         </View>
        );
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your can try this

```
import {withNavigation} from 'react-navigation'
  class Home extends React.Component{
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <ScrollView>
          <View style={styles.welcomContainer}>
          {/* so this one in here actually works fine but i want them wrap inside my 
   Cards Class */}
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => 
 this.props.navigation.navigate('creator')}>
              <CT.ReadmoreText/>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
          <Cards imageUri={require('../assets/images/cprofile_2.jpg')} distance="30" 
          />
          <Cards imageUri={require('../assets/images/cprofile_1.jpg')} distance="34" 
          />
          <Cards imageUri={require('../assets/images/cprofile_1.jpg')} distance="20" 
           />
          <Cards imageUri={require('../assets/images/cprofile_3.jpg')} distance="10" 
          />
        </ScrollView>
       </View>
     );
    }
   }
  export default withNavigation(Home);

 const Cards = () => (
  <View style={{padding: 30, flexDirection: 'row', borderBottomColor: '#6a6a6a', 
borderBottomWidth: 0.4}}>
    <View>
       <Image source={this.props.imageUri} style={styles.profileIcon} />
       <Image source={images.broShakeLogo} style={styles.broShakeLogo} />
    </View>
    <View style={{paddingLeft: 40, flexDirection: 'column'}}>
         .....
          <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('creator')} >
       .....
   );
```

Answer (score 0):

You have passed `navigation` as props,

```
<Cards imageUri={require('../assets/images/cprofile_2.jpg')} distance="30" navigation={this.props.navigation}/>
```

So, you need to use it as `this.props.navigation.navigate('....');`

but you have used it as `navigation.navigate('....');`

change it and it will work.

Comment: Wow, o my lord, problem solved. Thank you Jaydeep! Can't believe I spent an hour on this!